# How do I fix my app from crashing after camera capture?

Tags: android, android-camera

My app takes picture from camera and display it to another activity. Also, it is required to store and retrieve data from Firebase.

But, App crashes after the picture is taken and click ok from the camera.
Also, there is no log cat exception I get. What to do?
// Below is the activity where the camera is called:

## HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private File imageFile;
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String timeStamp= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName="IMAGE_"+timeStamp+"_";

            //Adding Camera Intent when clicked on the FAB
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    //What Happens After the Image is Captured
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this,"File saved to"+imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PostActivity.class);
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Uri uri=data.getData();
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_VALUE",photo);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## SectionsPagerAdapter.java

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       switch (position){
           case 0:
               AllPosts allposts=new AllPosts();
               return allposts;
           case 1:
               MyPosts myposts=new MyPosts();
               return myposts;
           default:
               return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "All Posts";
            case 1:
                return "My Posts";

         }
        return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the code where the image should be displayed in imageview

## PostActivity.java

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton mImageSelect;
    private EditText postTitle;
    private EditText postDescription;
    private Button submitButton;
    private TextView changeImage;
    private Uri imageUri=null;
    private StorageReference storage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialogue;
    private DatabaseReference database;
    public  String titleVal;
    public String descriptionVal;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        storage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

        mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        postTitle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        postDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.descriptionField);
        submitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submitPost);

        progressDialogue=new ProgressDialog(this);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("EXTRA_VALUE");
        imageUri=getIntent().getData();
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("titleVal", titleVal);
        outState.putString("descriptionVal",descriptionVal );
    }

    private void startPosting() {
        titleVal=postTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        descriptionVal=postDescription.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(descriptionVal) && imageUri!=null){
            progressDialogue.setMessage("আপলোড হচ্ছে......");
            progressDialogue.show();

            StorageReference filePath=storage.child("post_images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(PostActivity.this).load(downloadUrl).into(mImageView);
                    DatabaseReference newPost=database.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(titleVal);
                    newPost.child("description").setValue(descriptionVal);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

                    progressDialogue.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new   Intent(PostActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide a Title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check `data` is not null. `if(data != null)` { //put code here }

Comment: @AnkitaShah I guess u are talking about this line of code:if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(descriptionVal) && imageUri!=null)   //But I don't find anything wrong with it. Why do u think there could be a problem?

Comment: @Shoumma Rauth: I am talking about onActivityResult(). You are using  data parameter. Before use it check it is null or not.

Comment: @ShoummoRauth, what is probably null is that *Intent data* in the argument of *onActivityResult*, this happens to many people, especially in samsung phones. as Ankita said you need to check it `if(data == null){..//data is null...}`

Comment: Someone should have asked about more information, like the stacktrace. It might be an exception on the camera app but there is an exception to every crash (well each I have seen). Also, please erformat this code, there is blank line everywhere, this could divde by 2 the height. And did you debug your program ? This seems to happend in the activityResult, check the variable values there.

Comment: @AxelH  I did debug. But, there wasn't any exception. I am still stuck with it. The thing is I need to send the image to another activity and display it there. And after that I need to send the image to the firebase db. So I need to send the Uri to the second activity right?

Comment: Maybe, that's not the point. Here you seems to crash during the recovery of the Intent data but you can't confirm since your debbuging didn't show you anything so we need to guess. Just create a [mcve] of this (just the part to recover a picture) to be able to reproduce that. From there, maybe we could see the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use camera to take picture, your data is always null.

Try to start activity in following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
String path;
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appdir";
} else {
    path = activity.getCacheDir() + "/appdir";
}
String filePath = path + "/image.jpg";
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, StaticStorage.selectedImageFromCamera);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

And on onActivityResult() you can retrieve you captured image Uri from `StaticStorage.selectedImageUri`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code may be helpful to you.

First declare a variable

```
private static final int PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE = 2;
private Uri imageCaptureUri;
```

and after that add the following code on button click or onCreate()

```
Intent intent = new ntent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/imgDirectory", "imgName"+ ".png");

                imageCaptureUri= Uri.fromFile(file);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageCaptureUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE);
```

and in onActivityResult get image from imageCaptureUri and show image in imageview.

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE:                    
                img.setImageURI(imageCaptureUri);
                break;
        }
    }
```

If you want to send URI from one activity to another, you can send this URI by using intent.
In onActivityResult use this below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageCaptureUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
img.setImageURI(imageCaptureUri);.
```

and then just convert back to string like this in another activity and set new created uri to imageview.

```
 Uri newUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"));
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 img.setImageURI(newUri);
```

Comment: That i can do but I want to display and send the image into a new activity. What to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I was just wondering do I need "intent data" as onActivityResult as parameter, cause it seems that the data is null and probably as a result the app crashes.

Comment: @ShoummoRauth If it's working as per your requirement, please accept this as an answer so it's helpful for other guys.